# Conditionally set text in Google AppSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-appsheet

I am evaluating Google AppSheet. I have a Google Sheet with the following structure:

```
| items                                           |
| date       | time | category | name             |
|------------|------|----------|------------------|
|            |      | sports   | leather football |
|            |      | sports   | basketball       |
| 11-11-2021 | 9:00 | sports   | tennis ball      |
```

I'm working to display this sheet as a card view with a list layout. The title should be the `date`/`time`. The subtitle should be the `name`. My challenge, as shown in the table above, is that sometimes, I do *not* have a date or time. In those scenarios, I would like to render the title as "Unknown". Basically, the psuedocode below shows what I want to do:

```
if (date exists) {
  title = 'Arriving on ' + date;
} else {
  title = 'Unknown';
}
```

I do not see a way to do this in a Google AppSheet though. I have to believe I'm missing something. I assumed I would be able to do it via a Format Rule. However, it doesn't seem like I can specify conditional text. I can only set things like the color, font, etc. But, I do not see a way to add something like the conditional I showed above.

How can I conditionally set text in a Google AppSheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

If you get the value of a cell and it's a valid date, it should return a `Date` object. So you can use this condition to validate the object type:

```
var date = range.getValue();

if (date.constructor.toString().indexOf("Date") > -1) {
  title = 'Arriving on ' + date;
} else {
  title = 'Unknown';
}
```

**Sample check:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Check if object type is Date](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_isdate)

Comment: I understand this. What I don't understand though is, how to create custom text in an App Sheet based on the value of one or more cells. It seems like you're forced to pollute your spreadsheet. If you want to handle these scenarios. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can set [conditional format rules](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder) in Apps Script to format your range based on value. So for example, you can have one format if the value of the cell is "Unknown" and another format otherwise.

Comment: If you need something more specific, please upload a sample spreadsheet with inputs and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Another Option is Appsheet's virtual column. In the Data section on the Columns tab. Click your data source and then click the add virtual column button. You can then use something like this formula.

IF(ISBLANK([items date]), "Unknown", CONCAT("Arriving On: ",[items date]))

name it something like items_date_formmated

Then display this column in your card view form and hide the original date column by unchecking the is visible option.

Repeat for the time